# Entity Framework + LINQ request

Tags: c#

I am new to Entity Framework and Linq, I would like to understand how dbset/dbcontext works when executing the following kind of LINQ request:

```
from x in db.Products select x
```

`db` is the data context object, `Products` the dataset.

Is the search/loading of these records done directly at the base table level or is a first search done on the dbset? And then we complete and retrieve the records that are not yet tracked/in the dbset?

In other words what is the path of the loading of these elements?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

`Is the search/loading of these records done directly at the base table level or is a first search done on the dbset?`

It's done so at the "base table level" in the Database Server by receiving the results directly from the query and then DataContext will return any existing entity that it already have track of and create new entities if it doesn't have any track for those records.

`And then we complete and retrieve the records that are not yet tracked/in the dbset?`

The DataContext will create new entities for those records and it'll be tracked if you didn't explicitly specify AsNoTracking.

`In other words what is the path of the loading of these elements?`

The way it works from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) is that when you make a LINQ Query like this:

`from x in db.Products select x`

It will generates a LINQ Expression and then pass that expression to the Database Provider to generate the actual database query specific to the database engine it's made for (it may not have all of the query compiled, so some of the query may be computed from the application side.)

It will then execute the query and receive the result from that query and if the query is made with tracking, then it'll return any existing entity that the DataContext already have track of and create new entities if not.

The entity and record will be tied by the key and whenever [there is any part of the query using Keyless Entity Type, the whole query would be made as a NoTracking query.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking)

Note that if the database record for such existing entity have changed, it will not update the values in the existing entity, you will have to manually reload that entity like so:

`db.Entry(product).ReloadAsync();`